# spring boot with bluemix error: None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-cloud

Steps:

1. create new project with start.spring.io
2. run it localy - works
3. run gradle task `jar`
4. push jar to bluemix `cf push demoWar.jar`

> Downloaded app package (20.1M) Staging... None of the buildpacks
>   detected a compatible application Exit status 222 Staging failed:
>   Exited with status 222 Destroying container
>
> FAILED Error restarting application: NoAppDetectedError
>
> TIP: Buildpacks are detected when the "cf push" is executed from
>   within the dire ctory that contains the app source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try two things:
1. Use the -p command to target your deployable artifact. This would look something like cf p APP_NAME -p PATH_TO_YOUR_WAR. I usually chain my build and deploy commands so: mvn clean package && cf p APP_NAME -p PATH_TO_YOUR_WAR.

2. If this doesn't work then you can specify a build pack. So cf p APP_NAME -p PATH_TO_YOUR_WAR -b SOME_BUILDPACK. You can see the available build packs by calling cf buildpacks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

When deploying first time your app on cloud foundry then following command will not work

```
cf push TestService
```

you need to use following command

```
cf push -p  TestService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar testService
```

Useful link :

- https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/226273647-Troubleshooting-error-None-of-the-buildpacks-detected-a-compatible-application-exit-status-222-
- https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/detection.html

Else add manifest.yml on root

```
applications:
- name: Demo
  memory: 2G
  disk_quota: 2G
  instances: 1
  path: target/demo-local-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  env: 
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE : "dev"

routes:
- route: demo.app.dev.vk.vaquar.khan.com
```

after that go to path and run cf push < JAR_NAME>